# I would like to "exchange" my Stack Exchange Shop order

Tags: support, shop

Just got my SO shirt in the mail today. Unfortunately the sizes run a little small, I need a different size. Is there a way I can exchange it for a bigger size?

I didn't see any information about exchanges this on the shop site or in the packing slip.

Comment: Thank you for contacting the StackExchange Swag Shop.  Please listen carefully, as all of our options have changed.  For Customer Service, press one.  For Technical Support, press two.  For Waffles, press three.  For Unicorns...

Comment: So I guess I am probably stuck with the size I have.

Comment: @Robert:  `3`,`3`,`3`.

Comment: @Rocket **LISTEN TO ALL OF THE OPTIONS!! THEY HAVE CHANGED!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

email store@stackexchange.com with your issue.