# Stack Exchange store garment sizes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, shop

With reference to this question:

> [I would like to “exchange” my Stack Exchange Shop order.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94690/i-would-like-to-exchange-my-stack-exchange-shop-order)

I'm about to order a couple things from the store but I find that S/M/L/XL/XXL/XXXL garment sizes vary wildly from one t-shirt manufacturer to another and would rather not have the hassle of sending stuff back to the US from Europe if it's the wrong size.

It would be useful to have a sizing chart listing what S/M/L/XL/XXL/XXXL mean in terms of actual inches or centimetres (chest size, length).

Comment: +1, I have the same experience.

Comment: How many other online stores provide this information?

Comment: @jjnguy - Virtually all of the ones I've used. It's fairly normal to do that, for example: [thinkgeek](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/generic/b597/sizing/), [cafepress](http://www.cafepress.co.uk/cp/moredetails.aspx?productNo=57139393&colorNo=6&pr=F&showbleed=false&tab=3), [jinx](http://www.jinx.com/p/minecraft_three_creeper_moon_premium_tee.html) to name a few.

Comment: @Kev, interesting, I had no idea.

Comment: @jjnguy - that's because you're probably a "normal sized" person and wouldn't think twice, I however have abused my waistline over the years with beer and curry.... :)

Comment: @Kev Mmmm beer....Mmmmm curry!

Comment: @Kev - I'm looking into if we can get this for our various items.  If we can, we'll definitely make it available

Comment: @alex - excellent.

Comment: For T-Shirt sizes, see this answer on [meta.WebApps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/823/webapps-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users/826#826)

Comment: @alex - can you see @barry's comment above. Can you make an official answer out of that info for MSO? I'm guessing those numbers are inches and not centimetres or Potrzebies?

Comment: @kev - Yes, those number are inches, not centimeters.  We should have a page on the store with sizes by early next week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sizing charts have now been added to the "Ordering Info" page of the Stack Exchange Shop.  You can access it from the menu bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: Can you include the t-shirt "make" there too?  I assume it is consistent if the sizes are consistent, and it is very helpful to me since I can just compare to other t-shirts I already own without having to measure.  Like I know I wear L in American Apparel and M in Hanes Beefy-T.