# After a feature has been implemented, if it is removed should the feature request be closed?

Tags: discussion, support

[Stack Overflow changed their logo this weekend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1) as per the feature request.

It is going to be changed back to the old one some time today, (00:00 UTC probably).

Should the feature request be closed when that happens, or are feature requests left open? I know they are for status declined questions, so I guess they should be in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Those requests are usually closed with the second off-topic close reason:

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

typically because of the second sentence of this reason: *Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete*. But even this step is not almost "required".

Nothing else is done, and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is (usually) left on its place.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I have found discussions with this, but no feature requests closed for this reason.

Comment: @Tim http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc is the first I found.

Comment: @Tim second: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit

Comment: @Tim maybe some other reasons for closure, but here's another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95050/stack-exchange-store-garment-sizes

Comment: Hmm okay then .